# Can I get a rundown of what happens during the Window Loading/Initialization in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, load, window

I'm trying to understand how it all comes together, but there's a lot of methods and classes involved and trying to understand how it goes I just end up getting lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WPF Windows Overview from MSDN has a reasonably full explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948.aspx#Opening_a_Window).